# How to validate and collect errors from CSV import without submission failure

Tags: views, feeds, forms, importing-exporting

I have been tasked with creating a tool which accepts a CSV and presents it in a spreadsheet display with additional dialogues to explain and link to errors on the display.

Have investigated / experimented with several approaches using combinations of Views, Feeds, Sheetnode and Field Validation modules. I've found no issues when CSV is precisely formatted.

The problem is that all of the modular / Drupal validation mechanisms will cause the import to fail or disallow values from being added to fields. I'm looking for a mechanism which will accept all data but gather the errors to allow display and guidance to the user on where mistakes lie - so they can fix and resubmit a corrected CSV. I can't find hooks that would facilitate this.

It seems pointless to write a whole bunch of custom code, when there is so much in the way of Drupal validation stuff that could be taken advantage of (if I could only figure out how???)

Comment: Which "Drupal validation stuff" are you talking about specifically? If you mean the FAPI validation then you're out of luck - that's for validating forms, and importing a CSV will surely use a batch job

Comment: By validation stuff, I mean code within various field modules, Feeds, Migrate, Field Validation et al. But I'm not sure now to harness them in this context.

Comment: Those things are all written for specific contexts, which you're not in during a batch job. You could call the appropriate validation functions directly, but before that you'll need to re-write the CSV batch job to a) actually run those functions and keep track of specific errors, and b) change the batch completion function to report the errors to the user. I would imagine that being a medium - large sized job, certainly not a quick thing

Comment: Yup, looking like there are no quick fixes for this.